# Is it possible to send a reason for Jasmine 2 specs skipped with xit or pending()?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

When we find a bug with one of our Protractor Jasmine2 specs, we usually want to skip the test until the bug has been resolved.

I know how to do this with `xit` or `pending()`, and JasmineReporters TerminalReporter is doing a nice job of color highlighting and listing pending specs.

However, the pending tests always report `No reason given`, which implies it is possible to give a reason for the skipped test.

I currently comment the spec with an issue number, but it would be really nice to report the reason the test was disabled and the issue number.

UPDATE

As requested, adding example terminal output ( fdescribe on an example, so reporting most of the suite disabled ):

Versions:
Protractor 2.1.0  and Jasmine 2.3.1

Using `xit`

```
 Skipped
*      will display the platform if available ...
...
SUCCESS: 85 specs, 0 failures, 1 skipped, 72 disabled in 34.734s.
Pending:

1) will display the platform if available
No reason given
```

Using `pending()`

This appears to have started marking it failed, probably related to https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1852

```
Failures:
1) will display the platform if available
Message:
Failed: => marked Pending
Stack:
Error: Failed: => marked Pending
```

**UPDATED: Related feature requests and issues for this functionality**

There is currently a feature request to support pending(message) outstanding for Protractor/jasminewd if you want to follow progress :

https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/issues/32 https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2454

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Another way would be to call the `pend` method on the test itself:

```
xit('Pending test description', function() {
    // test body
}).pend('Reason for being disabled');
```

Answer (score 12):

`pending()` receives a single `message` argument which is actuall a "pending reason":

```
pending("doesn't work, issue #123")
```

FYI, here is the initial feature request:

- [Pending specs overview](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/671)

and the official docs:

- [jasmine pending docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction#section-18)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, and not currently documented on Jasmine docs.  As soon as the Protractor issue with pending() is resolved this should work well.