# Mocha - Setting message (reason) for test skip

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io

Is it possible to set a message (mentioning reason) why a particular test is skipped, so that it could be used in reporters.

```
describe('xxx', function() {
 checkToSkip(1)("test1", function() {\*test goes here*\});
 checkToSkip(4)("test2", function() {\*test goes here*\});
});

function checkToSkip(now) {
    return now > 3 ? it : xit; 
   //return now > 3 ? it : it.skip; 
}
```

Here 'test1' will be skipped as 'checkToSkip' returns 'xit' (or it.skip). Is it possible to pass a message to reporter mentioning the reason for the test skip? something like below (or any other possible way).

```
checkToSkip(4)("test2", function() { \\ test goes here}, "My Skip message!!!!" );
```

Note: Im using mocha in webdriverIO.

Thanks.

Comment: below thread explains the solution for problem using Jasmine. Im looking for something similar in Mocha.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688650/is-it-possible-to-send-a-reason-for-jasmine-2-specs-skipped-with-xit-or-pending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just slightly modify the `checkToSkip` function and used [Pending Tests](https://mochajs.org/#pending-tests) instead of `skip()`.

```
function checkToSkip(now, title, testCallable) {
    if (now > 3) {
        it(title, testCallable);
    } else {
        it(title+"#My Skip message!#");
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
describe('xxx', function() {
    checkToSkip(1, "test1", function() {\*test goes here*\});
});
```

Comment: Even it(title) cannot pass any message explaining the reason why this test is skipped/pending.

Comment: @VNP Why you can't put the reason why it's pending into the `title`?

Comment: Many test cases are implemented using above method, there will be huge impact

Comment: this is definitely a workaround, but is there any API way for this? i Know mocha documentation is not efficient.

Comment: @@martin -This seems to be only and the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to modify the test title itself inside the test before skipping:

```js
it('My cool test', async function() {
  if (this.response.status !== 201) {
   this._runnable.title += ' - Skipped with reason: wrong response code'
   this.skip()
  }
  expect(this.response.data).to.have.property('mycoolproperty')
})
```

Also possible to formalize the check and move it to the external function:

```js
function skipIf(that, condition, reason){
  if (condition) {
    that._runnable.title += ` - Skipped with reason: ${reason}`
    that.skip()
  }
}
```

So the test will look like that:

```js
it('My cool test', async function() {
  skipIf(this, this.response.status !==201, 'Wrong response status')
  expect(this.response.data).to.have.property('mycoolproperty')
})
```